# La oración "(...) para que dé tan poco valor a la propia vida", ¿es final o consecutiva?

Tags: sintaxis

¿Es la parte en negrita una oración final o consecutiva?

> ¿Qué le pasa a su generación **para que dé tan poco valor a la propia
>   vida**?

Sé que oraciones finales vienen introducidas por la conjunción final *para que*. Pero si lo pongo así: algo pasa a aquella generación y en consecuencia de esto dan poco valor a la vida, creo que esta es una oración consecutiva. Por otro lado las oraciones consecutivas no van introducidas por el nexo *para que*. Entonces ¿qué tipo de oración es esta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La interpretación consecutiva me parece más apropiada. La frase se puede reformular añadiendo un *como* antes del *para* sin que cambie de significado:

> ¿Qué le pasa a su generación *como* para que dé tan poco valor a la propia vida?

El DPD no tiene ninguna entrada para *para*, pero sí tiene una para [*como*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=como), donde se puede leer (apartado 2.f):

> f) Seguido de la preposición *para + infinitivo*, o de *para que + verbo* en subjuntivo, introduce la **consecuencia posible o esperable** de lo expresado con anterioridad: *«Se sabía [...] con el encanto suficiente como para embelesar a Joaquín»* (Elizondo Setenta [Méx. 1987]); *«Era un local lo bastante amplio como para que pudieran entrenar allí dos docenas de boxeadores»* (Memba Homenaje [Esp. 1989]). La mayor parte de las veces [el *como*] tiene simplemente valor ponderativo y **puede suprimirse** sin que cambie el sentido del enunciado.

La lógica del DPD es la misma que la que has dado tú: "tenía el encanto suficiente, y en consecuencia podía embelesar a Joaquín". En tu caso el razonamiento sería, efectivamente, "algo le pasa a esta gente, y en consecuencia no dan valor a la propia vida". El ejemplo del DPD podría ser igual al tuyo si se expresa como una pregunta:

> ¿Qué tiene [como] para embelesar a Joaquín? El encanto suficiente.

Comment: ¡muchísimas gracias! : )